# Adding Multiple Children of the Same Object As3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been working on a flash project and I am making an achievements display with each achievement progress complete and reward for completing. I would like to add multiple textFields to the stage and add text to each one individually. I have 30 text boxes and I think there is a better way of adding them than making different classes for each.

```
public var progress1:textField = new textField();
public var progress2:textField = new textField();
public var progress3:textField = new textField();
public var progress4:textField = new textField();

...And so on until 30
```

Is there a way of adding them and changing their text with a for loop because this does not seem like an efficient way to do it.
I also have to add a movie clip to the stage 30 times and change its y each time is there a way of making that in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the textfields in a vector like this.

```
var texts:Vector.<TextField> = new Vector.<TextField>();

var num:int = 30;

for (var i:int = 0; i < num; i++)
{
   texts.push(new TextField());
}

//change the text in a loop;
var content:Array = ["text1", "text2" ...];//the contents for the texts to show

var max:int = Math.max(content.length, texts.length);

for (var j:int = 0; j < max; j++)
{
   texts[j].text = content[j];
}
```